# ServiceStack request batching from Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, http, servicestack

Has anyone figured out a way to batch http requests from a javascript client to a ServiceStack service? I have done this many times from a .NET client using [.SendAll()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Batched-Requests#all-services-support-batching) but I haven't found a way to do it from javascript. From my understanding ss-utils.js does not have a function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sending a Batched Request](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-batched-requests#request-execution-flow) to ServiceStack just involves POST'ing an Array of Request DTOs to the built-in route:

```
/json/reply/Request[]
```

Where `Request` is the name of your Request DTO.